# react functional component 再レンダーされない

Tags: reactjs

react のhooksを使ってsetStateを呼びだしたときに、再レンダリングが走りません。
なぜでしょうか？
todoアプリのdeleteを押したときに、stateの値は更新されているようですが、再描画が走りません。
stateには配列を入れて、更新をしているはずなのですが。。
以下、コードです。

```
// app.txs
const App = () =>{
const [todo, setTodo] = React.useState<String[]>([])
// データ保存
function handleAdd(e:any){
    e.preventDefault()
    setTodo(todo.concat(e.target.title.value))
    e.target.title.value=""
}
// データ削除
const handleRemove = (i:number)=>{
    // todo 配列のi番目から1つ目のデータを除外
    todo.splice(i,1)
    setTodo(todo)
    console.log(todo)
}
return(
    <div>
        <h1>React Todo App</h1>
        <Form handleAdd={handleAdd} />
        <div></div>
        <List todos={todo} handleRemove={handleRemove} />
    </div>
)
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("app"))


// List.tsx
const List = (props: any) =>{
return (
<ul>
    {props.todos.map((v:any, i:any) =>{
        return <li key={i}>{v} <span style={{cursor: "pointer"}} onClick={()=>{props.handleRemove(i)}}>delete</span></li>
    })}
</ul>
)}
export default List
```

Answer (score 3):

useState hookでは、同じ値で更新した場合、子のレンダリングを回避します。ここで "同じ値" の意味は`Object.is(古いstate, 新しいstate)`が`true`という意味です。

出典: https://ja.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update

> state 更新の回避
>
> 現在値と同じ値で更新を行った場合、React は子のレンダーや副作用の実行を回避して処理を終了します。（React は Object.is による比較アルゴリズム を使用します）

添付されたコードを見ると`todo.splice`で`todo`を直接変更し、その同じ`todo`Arrayインスタンスを`setTodo`に渡しているため、`Object.is`による比較は`true`となることが推察されます。

以下、解決策のひとつです。

```
const handleRemove = (i: number) => {
    // todo をコピーして、新しいArrayインスタンスを作成する。
    const newTodo = [...todo];
    // ここで Object.is(todo, newTodo) === false となります。
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is

    // newTodo 配列のi番目から1つ目のデータを除外
    newTodo.splice(i, 1);

    setTodo(newTodo);
}
```

もしくは次のようにも書けます。

```
const handleRemove = (i: number) => {
    setTodo([...todo.slice(0, i), ...todo.slice(i + 1)]);
}
```

なお`handleAdd`内で使われている`concat`は新しいArrayインスタンスを返すので子のレンダリングは必ず行われます。`push`を使って直接変更し、同じ`todo`を渡した場合は再レンダリングされません。

```
// 再描画されない例
const handleAdd = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    todo.push(e.target.title.value);
    setTodo(todo);
    console.log(todo); // 新しい要素が追加された`todo`が出力される
    e.target.title.value = "";
};
```

Comment: 丁寧な回答ありがとうございますm(_ _)m

Answer (score 0):

stateの配列の変更は、immutablity-helperなるものを使うそうです。